# How to Ask a Muslim if He Adheres to strict Halal tradition

Tags: etiquette

I would like to invite a Muslim friend and his family over for dinner and want to know how to casually inquire if they are strict Halal when it comes to food so that we can make the appropriate adjustments if need be. Or, can it be as easy as asking "Are you Halal?"

Duplicate question issue:
I do not consider this a duplicate question as the linked question doesn't cover my specific request of how to talk about Halal issues (they talk about everything but...). I'm merely asking for examples - I don't even know how to use the term "Halal" or if I should even use it.  Is it the same as/similar to "Kosher". Is it wrong to even suggest that kind of comparison?  I imagine there are also varying degrees of adherence. It would be great to be able talk about it with some semblance of dignity without having to ask "Do you guys....?"

Comment: Why not just be direct?

Comment: @Rushba Mehta I would, I just don't know the correct terminology to ask with. I just don't want to appear ignorant/insensitive.

Comment: @squidlydeux You are ignorant-- that's what it means to not know. And you won't become an expert by asking random people on the internet, though you can gain some good information that way sometimes. Asking about Halal specifically (which is similar to keeping Kosher) doesn't seem important to me-- why can't you ask about dietary restrictions in general, which would elicit the same information, plus cover other important questions (such as food allergies)?